# Django Filter through Form input not working

Tags: python, django

After clicking on the Filter button it shouldn't return the property with 20000 rent. But that is not happening. Anyone can explain why? I have attached the template, view, and form code below.
[image]
Template code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <form action="/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" value="Filter">
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 row" id="filtered-product">
        {% for l in listings %}
        <div class="card w-25 float-left p-2">
            <img src="{{ l.image.url }}" class="img-fluid" alt="">
            <h3 class="card-title text-center">{{ l.type }}</h3>
            <h5 class="card-subtitle text-center">Rent: {{ l.rent }}</h5>
            <a href="/listings/{{ l.id }}/" class="btn btn-primary">
                View details
            </a>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

View:

```
def listing_list(request):
    form = FilterForm()

    if form.is_valid():
        min_price = form.cleaned_data["minrent"]
        max_price = form.cleaned_data["maxrent"]
        listings = listings.filter(rent__gte=min_price)
        listings = listings.filter(rent__lte=max_price)
    else:
        listings = Listing.objects.all().select_related('user')

    context = {
        "listings": listings,
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "listings/listings.html", context)
```

Form:

```
class FilterForm(forms.Form):
   minrent = forms.IntegerField()
   maxrent = forms.IntegerField()
```

Comment: IDK, if this will fix the problem, but you can pass multiple arguments to `filter()`: `listings.filter(rent__lte=max_price, rent__gte=min_price)`.

Comment: With that said, where do you initialize `listings`? You are doing `listings = listings.filter(...)`, but where does `listings get assigned initially?

Comment: On a side note, why are you doing `.select_related('user')`? Do you know what this is for? If not, I recommend you remove it because it causes Django to generate a more complex query than you need for what you are doing here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes, I know its a foreign key. I am using it to access information from another table. And how should I initially assign listings? Can you elaborate, please.
And the multiple arguments didn't work.

Comment: Well, from the code you posted here, you will get an NameError because `listings` is not defined. I suspect that your actual code is different than what you posted here. Please [edit] your code so that it reflects the code you are running on your computer.